# Ошибка "can't address with currently assumed segment registers" во всех строках с операциями

Tags: ассемблер

```
text  SEGMENT
    ORG 100h 
begin:  a dw 23h, 0AEh, 0EAh
        c1 dw 2Bh
        c2 dw 5Dh
            MOV ax,a+4
            ADD ax,a
            SUB ax,a+2
            MOV bx,a+2
            ADD bx,a
            MOV cx,c2
            SUB cx,c1
            MOV cl,5
            MOV dx,a
            ROR dx,cl
            XOR dx,a+2
            NOT dx
        RET 
text    ENDS   
        END begin
```

Answer (score 1):

Сегмент данных не определён, нужна строка, которая перенесёт константы в сегмент данных *ds*, а также нужно определить область кода, сегмент *сs*, делается это так

`assume cs:code,ds:text`

Рабочий код вашей программы

```
ORG 100h 
data segment 
    a dw 23h, 0AEh, 0EAh
    c1 dw 2Bh
    c2 dw 5Dh   
data ends
code segment  
    assume cs:code,ds:text
begin:  
            mov ax,a+4
            add ax,a
            sub ax,a+2
            mov bx,a+2
            add bx,a
            mov cx,c2
            sub cx,c1
            mov cl,5
            mov dx,a
            ror dx,cl
            xor dx,a+2
            not dx
        ret   
end begin
```